# Javascript for loop to change the name of textareas in a function

Tags: javascript, for-loop, textarea, onload

I have created 50 `textareas` with names `def1,def2,def3.....,def50`. In my body `onLoad()` function,I want the same value is set in all these textboxes.

Instead of writing the code 50 times, How can I write some Javascript code to set the value of the `textarea`, ie in a loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use tagname property but it will not work if you have some more textbox anywhere else in your page

```
 function loader(){
    for(var i=0;i<50;i++)
    document.getElementsByName("def"+i)[0].value='Any Value';
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to read the [*MDC JavaScript guide*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide), as loops and string concatenation are fairly basic operations:

```
for(var i = 1; i < 51; i++) {
    var nameOfTextarea = 'def' + i;
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would give your textboxes ID's (not just names) if possible, and then do something like the following:

```
var namePrefix = "def";
for(var i = 1; i <= 50; ++i)
{
    var textbox = getElementById(namePrefix + i);
    // do something to textbox number i.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try jquery for this:

```
<input type="text" id="t1"/>
<input type="text" id="t2"/>
<input type="text" id="t3"/>
```

The Jquery code:

```
var arr = [ "t1", "t2", "t3" ];
jQuery.each(arr, function() {
      $("#"+this).val("hello");//$("#" + this).text("hello");
   });
```

Here is [the working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u8jcN/)

Comment: I'd give all the inputs the same class, then wrap all inputs in one container div with an ID. `$("#container .inputClass")...`

Comment: Its your wish to do it your way. I suggested mine.

Comment: Uhh...right. That's how this place works. We all suggest solutions.

Comment: Yup I know this fact well enough. So your suggestions are always welcome, but if it were put up as an answer, rather than a comment

Comment: Sure, I certainly didn't mean to imply your suggestion was in any way wrong. Was merely throwing out another way to create the selector (not that implying that it's a better solution...merely another to consider)

Comment: I liked your solution. But if you could have given it as an answer, i could have given you an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
var textareas = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea");
for(var i=0;i<textareas.length;i++){
    if(textareas[i].id.indexOf("def") == 0){
        textareas[i].value = textareas[i].id;
    }
}
```