# javascript code to change name of function

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop

I have 300 functions with name cloud1=cloud300 that are called onclick on 300 buttons(names of buttons - button1-button300) to change class of 300 textboxes with name tree1-tree300.How can I do this using for loop.

```
function cloud1(){document.formname.tree1.className="css"}
function cloud2(){document.formname.tree2.className="css"}
function cloud3(){document.formname.tree3.className="css"}
```

Comment: Assuming the code is mostly the same in all functions, have you considered solving it using an argument? Can you post the code?

Comment: could1 to cloud3 would be enough for now :)

Comment: Your user interface has 300 buttons? I don't even know what would justify that...

Comment: I'm linking his other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6235213/javascript-for-loop-to-change-the-name-of-textareas-in-a-function since it might be related to this one...

Comment: Consider using just one function as a listener on the buttons container, so it can intercept bubbling events.

Comment: That's not your real code. I can tell by the way it's full of errors.

Comment: There _has_ to be an elegant way to solve this :) Are you using any js library by any chance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass input name as parameter to

```
function button(inputname){
document.formname.inputname.className='css';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First - create a click handler that works irrespective of which button is clicked - this one figures out the name of the supplied element, and replaces `button` with `tree`:

```
function clicker(ev) {
    ev = ev || window.event;
    var el = ev.target || ev.srcElement;
    var name = el.getAttribute('name');
    var tree = name.replace('button', 'tree');
    document.formname[tree].className = 'css';
}
```

Then, register that same handler on every button

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 300; ++i) {
    document.formname['button' + i].onclick = clicker;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/YHv52/ for a working demonstration.

Of course, it's easier with jQuery, particularly if you did the right thing and used the `id` attribute instead of the `name` attribute:

```
$('form[name="formname"] :button').live(function() {
    var button = this.id;
    var tree = button.replace('button', 'tree');
    $('#' + tree).addClass('css');
});
```

Comment: Are you sure that jquery code is functioning? You seem to have a quote where it shouldn't be? `$('#' + tree')` should be `$('#' + tree)`, right? And also, where is name coming from in `name.replace('button', 'tree')`?

Comment: fixed those thanks - was a quick (and admittedly still untested) example of how much shorter jQuery can make this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all functions are global, this should work:

```
for (var i=1; i <= 300; i++) {
  this['cloud'+i].call();
}
```

But as it was said above, please consider having one function and passing arguments to it. 300 similar functions are a refactoring opportunity.

Comment: Are you all addict of stack overflow or doing a job?

Comment: cloud1(){document.formname.testbox1.className="css"}cloud2(){document.formname.testbox2.className="css"} and so on

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately you don't need to add 300 event handlers for 300 elements. You can use [*event delegation*](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html) and attach **only one event handler** to an ancestor element (e.g. the `<form>`) which handles all the click events  and decides what to do. This should be [300x faster](http://jsperf.com/event-delegation-300). :)

Here is a **[demo](http://jsbin.com/eguku5/2/)** to show you how it works.

```
// add one event handler to the <form>
document.formname.onclick = function(e) {
    // normalize event for IE
    e = e || window.event;
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    // if a button was clicked
    if (target.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'button') {
        // generate tree name
        var name = target.name.replace('button', 'tree');
        // apply css class for this element
        document.formname[name].className = 'css';
    }
};
```

*Note: Assuming that `document.formname` is in the parent chain of all the buttons

(it can be simply `document`).*

Comment: No, it won't be 300x faster.  Sure, it avoids the need to register the event 300 times over, but that's hardly a significant overhead compared to the single handler, 300 registrations method.  In operation it'll be just the same speed.

Comment: If you do something 1x vs 300x it will be 300x faster whatever way you look at it, also only one event handler will be in memory. So it's `1.)` faster `2.)` uses less memory `3.)` easily extensible: the form can have any number of button-tree pairs.

Comment: 300x next to nothing is still next to nothing.  I don't dispute that the delegate model is cleaner than my answer, but only the 3rd of your points is actually correct when compared to having each element's `onclick` pointing at the same handler.

Comment: Next to nothing on your computer, it can be significant on a slower machine, netbook, mobile phone, old browser. I'm sorry to say, but you're ignorant and unmindful. http://jsperf.com/event-delegation-300

Comment: There's no need to get personal.  Your test shows it took (at worst) a couple of milliseconds with the "slow" method, and yes, somewhat faster with the delegate method.  My argument was that if it's only a couple of milliseconds, it doesn't really matter - 2ms, 6us - they're still both next to nothing.  FWIW, I don't think performance is really an issue for the OP...

Comment: It's an observation. You keep defending your clearly nonsense view of the world that if something works right and fast enough in your machine then it's considered done. Those numbers are from my computer, which is again, a fast one.

Comment: see: *"No, it won't be 300x faster."* and *"it'll be just the same speed."*

Comment: that "just the same speed" was referring to the subsequent page processing, not the event set up.

Answer (score 0):

You can write just one event handler that will take the id of the button (set to the handler name, for extensibility) as param :

```
<input type="button" id="cloud1" name="test_1" value="Click me"  onclick="handler(this.id)">

<script>

function handler(handler_id)
{
   this[handler_id].call();
}
```